# Linux Bash - load declared variable from textfile

Tags: linux, bash, variables, terminal

My situation :

Textfile : test.txt

> $test

Variable test declared in the terminal

> test=hello

Now when I cat the file, output is :

> $test

My question how can I cat the file with the declared output from the variable?

Comment: Do you mean you want the result of shell variable expansion on the text in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cat itself does not evaluate any variables. To do it, the command line must be evaluated by bash twice. This is done by the eval command. Thus the result should be

eval echo $(cat test.tex)

Comment: What would happen if the contents of the file contained, for example, ``foo `rm -rf /` bar`` ?

Comment: My solution is indeed fragile and insecure. If the text file contains `rm -rf /`, such command is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Add export in the file then execute it

example

```
export test="Hi I'm Ender"
```

Then try to

```
source ./blabla.txt
```

Note : You need echo not cat

Also your can use

```
test="Yes"
```

Or maybe your asking how to execute variable in script?

Comment: No export is required.